# How to do a loop which does operations in parts of a column in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am new in R so maybe this question its so simple, but I tried many approaches and none works for me.
I have a dataframe with columns consisting in two kind of values: 0 and non-zero. Zero represents normal conditions while other values represents dry/wet periods. I need an approach that, beginning in the first, sum and count all cells with values different to 0, stop when reach a cell with 0 and then continue until the end of the column. The idea is obtain the magnitude (sum) and longitude (count) of each dry/wet period.

I tried used this:

````
#Load data
library(readxl)
data<-read_xlsx("R_amplitud.xlsx")
a<-c () #Empty variable to save results

> print(data)
## A tibble: 8,440 x 2
   Date                `spei1_-1`
   <dttm>                   <dbl>
 1 1999-01-09 00:00:00       0   
 2 1999-01-16 00:00:00       0   
 3 1999-01-23 00:00:00       0   
 4 1999-02-01 00:00:00       0   
 5 1999-02-09 00:00:00       0   
 6 1999-02-16 00:00:00      -1.26
 7 1999-02-23 00:00:00       0   
 8 1999-03-01 00:00:00       0   
 9 1999-03-09 00:00:00       0   
10 1999-03-16 00:00:00       0   
11 1999-03-23 00:00:00       0   
12 1999-04-01 00:00:00       0   
13 1999-04-09 00:00:00      -1.23
14 1999-04-16 00:00:00      -1.29
15 1999-04-23 00:00:00      -1.99
# ... with 8,425 more rows

#Loop 1(I tried both)

for (i in 1:8440){if (data$`spei1_-1`!=0){a<-sum ()} else {next}}```

#Loop 2

for (value in data$`spei1_-1`){
                if(value!=0) {a = sum(data$`spei1_-1`)
    }else{ 
    next
    } 
  }
````

Using ifelse() comand:

```
a<-ifelse((data$`spei1_-1`!=0),sum (),"")
View(a)
```

For the 2 first loops I received the following warning:

```
> for (i in 1:8440){if (data$`spei1_-1`!=0){a<-sum ()} else {next}}
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In if (data$`spei1_-1` != 0) { ... :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
```

And for the ifelse () command I obtain the sum of anything (all cells with zero now are empty and cells with values now are 0).

```
> a<-ifelse((data$`spei1_-1`!=0),sum (),"")
> print(a)
   [1] ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "0" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
  [25] "0" "0" ""  ""  ""  ""  "0" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "0" "0" "0" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

If I change the sum argument by the data with are not zero I obtain the sum of all cells:

```
a<-ifelse((data$`spei1_-1`!=0),sum (data$`spei1_-1`!=0),"")
> print(a)
   [1] ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     "3344" ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     "3344"
  [14] "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344" "3344"
```

My expected results could be something like this where the two last column are the count and sums of cells with non-zero value for the Spei1_-1 variable

```
A tibble: 8,440 x 4
   Date                `spei1_-1` `COUNT_spei1_-1` `SUM_spei1_-1`
   <dttm>                   <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 1999-01-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
 2 1999-01-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
 3 1999-01-23 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
 4 1999-02-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
 5 1999-02-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
 6 1999-02-16 00:00:00      -1.26                1          -1.26
 7 1999-02-23 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
 8 1999-03-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
 9 1999-03-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
10 1999-03-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
11 1999-03-23 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
12 1999-04-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
13 1999-04-09 00:00:00      -1.23               NA          NA   
14 1999-04-16 00:00:00      -1.29               NA          NA   
15 1999-04-23 00:00:00      -1.99               NA          NA   
16 1999-05-01 00:00:00      -1.36               NA          NA   
17 1999-05-09 00:00:00      -1.31               NA          NA   
18 1999-05-16 00:00:00      -1.18               NA          NA   
19 1999-05-23 00:00:00      -1.44               NA          NA   
20 1999-06-01 00:00:00      -1.65               NA          NA   
21 1999-06-09 00:00:00      -1.15               NA          NA   
22 1999-06-16 00:00:00      -1.18               NA          NA   
23 1999-06-23 00:00:00      -1.11               NA          NA   
24 1999-07-01 00:00:00      -1.2                NA          NA   
25 1999-07-09 00:00:00      -1.44               NA          NA   
26 1999-07-16 00:00:00      -1.3                14         -18.8 
27 1999-07-23 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
28 1999-08-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
29 1999-08-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
30 1999-08-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
31 1999-08-23 00:00:00      -1.65                1          -1.65
32 1999-09-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
33 1999-09-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
34 1999-09-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
35 1999-09-23 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
36 1999-10-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
37 1999-10-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
38 1999-10-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
39 1999-10-23 00:00:00       1.38               NA          NA   
40 1999-11-01 00:00:00       1                  NA          NA   
41 1999-11-09 00:00:00       1.26                3           3.64
42 1999-11-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
43 1999-11-23 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
44 1999-12-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
45 1999-12-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
46 1999-12-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
47 1999-12-23 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
48 2000-01-01 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
49 2000-01-09 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
50 2000-01-16 00:00:00       0                  NA          NA   
# ... with 8,390 more rows
```

Any suggestion about how do it?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your data and the expected result you can use dput for example.

Comment: You can find the data in this link (I dont know how post it here). The two columns at the ending represent my expected result. Thank you very much https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pjYuitIiPF53Z2ojRHBtamaXon92Wvxz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101765535637334531649&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expected output.  If you're trying to get the sum of the `speil_-1` column, all you need is sum(data$`speil_-1`)

Comment: It's hard to read your expected output because there are so many extra columns that are not relevant for your question. Could you show the sample data and expected output without the spie3 through spie12 columns? And maybe omit the Year, Date, and plot columns as well, unless they are relevant?

Comment: I edited the post and included and example of expected output. As you can see for example in line 26, the count is the number of cells with numbers differs to zero above and the sum is the summatory of these cells. Note that cells with 0 not must be take in account. As the dataframe is weekly i know now that for 14 weeks I have a dry period and the magnitude is -18.8 in this case. I did it manually in excel but i have to for all dataframe so its not possible do manually :(

Comment: I think I understand the problem, but the data is difficult to import for me to test code on it the way you've shared. It would help a lot to give copy/pasteable data. `dput(data[1:30, c("DATA", "spei1_-1")])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 30 rows of the DATA and spei1_-1 columns, including all class and structure info. Can you please share that?

Comment: For sure Gregor. I did it without dates because the output is so large for paste here. Anyway dates are not important now. The output is: > dput(data[1:50, c( "spei1_-1")])
structure(list(`spei1_-1` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.26, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -1.23, -1.29, -1.99, -1.36, -1.31, -1.18, -1.44, -1.65, 
-1.15, -1.18, -1.11, -1.2, -1.44, -1.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.65, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.38, 1, 1.26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will produce the two columns that you want for each vector.  It uses `cumsum(x)==0` to identify the runs of non-zero `x` for the `ave` function to group over. Then tests within each group whether you have the last observation (and a non-zero group), and adds the required information.

The `cbind` is just to organise it here so you can see what is happening.

```
x=c(0,0,0,-1,-2,0,0,-0.5,0,0,-1)

cbind(
  x,
  SUM=ave( x=x, by=cumsum(x==0), FUN = function(x) ifelse(seq_along(x)==length(x) & x!=0,cumsum(x),NA)),
  COUNT=ave( x=x, by=cumsum(x==0), FUN = function(x) ifelse(seq_along(x)==length(x) & x!=0,length(x)-1,NA))
)
         x  SUM COUNT
 [1,]  0.0   NA    NA
 [2,]  0.0   NA    NA
 [3,]  0.0   NA    NA
 [4,] -1.0   NA    NA
 [5,] -2.0 -3.0     2
 [6,]  0.0   NA    NA
 [7,]  0.0   NA    NA
 [8,] -0.5 -0.5     1
 [9,]  0.0   NA    NA
[10,]  0.0   NA    NA
[11,] -1.0 -1.0     1
```